# how to prevent tables from jumping to the next section

Tags: tables, floats

How do prevent tables from jumping to the next section? in this example, tables 2 and 3 should belong to section 1 but they jump to section 2 which is irrelevant to that section. Please note this is a two-column latex template and the tables are big, so they need to span both columns. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[default,iicol]{sn-jnl}% Default with double column layout
\jyear{2021}%



%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{stfloats} 
%\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
%\usepackage{kantlipsum}


\begin{document}



\section{sec1}\label{sec1}
\lipsum[1-2]


%% TABLE 1
\begin{table*}[b]
\begin{center}
 \caption{TABLE 1}
\label{Tab1}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
name & job & title & age & address & status \\ 
\hline 
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\ 
\hline 
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\ 
\hline 
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\ 
\hline 
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\ 
\hline 
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\ 
\hline 
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[2-7]



%% TABLE 2
\begin{table*}[b]
\begin{center}
 \caption{TABLE 2}
\label{Tab2}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
name & job & title & age & address & status \\ 
\hline 
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\ 
\hline 
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\ 
\hline 
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\ 
\hline 
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\ 
\hline 
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\ 
\hline 
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table*}


 %% TABLE 3
\begin{table*}[b]
\begin{center}
 \caption{TABLE 3}
\label{Tab3}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
name & job & title & age & address & status \\ 
\hline 
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\ 
\hline 
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\ 
\hline 
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\ 
\hline 
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\ 
\hline 
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\ 
\hline 
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table*}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{sec2}\label{sec2}

\lipsum[1-2]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Tables in `table*` floats always appear on the top of the next page from where is inserted.
- Why you use `table*` environment (which span over both columns), when your showed table can be nicely fit in one column?

```
\documentclass[default,iicol]{sn-jnl}% Default with double column layout

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage{cuted}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}


%% TABLE 8
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{the jumping table}
\label{Jump}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Parameter & help & me & with & this & table \\
\hline
$IMO$ & 1 \% & 2 \% & 3 \% & 4 \% & 5\% \\
\hline
$IMO$ & 1 \% & 2 \% & 3 \% & 4 \% & 5\% \\
\hline
$IMO$ & 1 \% & 2 \% & 3 \% & 4 \% & 5\% \\
\hline
$IMO$ & 1 \% & 2 \% & 3 \% & 4 \% & 5\% \\
\hline
$IMO$ & 1 \% & 2 \% & 3 \% & 4 \% & 5\% \\
\hline
$IMO$ & 1 \% & 2 \% & 3 \% & 4 \% & 5\% \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum (1):**
Apparently OP table is so big, that it need to span both columns,. In this case may be of help package `stfloats` which enable to put table at bottom or to top of the same page where it is inserted:

```
\documentclass[default,iicol]{sn-jnl}% Default with double column layout

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage{stfloats}   % <-------
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

%% TABLE 8
\begin{table*}[b]
\centering
\caption{the jumping table}
\label{Jump}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Parameter & help & me & with & this & table \\
\hline
$IMO$ & 1 \% & 2 \% & 3 \% & 4 \% & 5\% \\
\hline
$IMO$ & 1 \% & 2 \% & 3 \% & 4 \% & 5\% \\
\hline
$IMO$ & 1 \% & 2 \% & 3 \% & 4 \% & 5\% \\
\hline
$IMO$ & 1 \% & 2 \% & 3 \% & 4 \% & 5\% \\
\hline
$IMO$ & 1 \% & 2 \% & 3 \% & 4 \% & 5\% \\
\hline
$IMO$ & 1 \% & 2 \% & 3 \% & 4 \% & 5\% \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\lipsum[2-7]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum (2):

- you should set `table*` positioning accordingly. In the case showed in the edited question, an MWE can be:

```
\documentclass[default,iicol]{sn-jnl}% Default with double column layout
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{sec1}\label{sec1}
\lipsum[1-2]

%% TABLE 1
\begin{table*}[b]   % <---
\centering
\caption{TABLE 1}
\label{Tab1}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
name & job & title & age & address & status \\
\hline
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\
\hline
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\
\hline
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\
\hline
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\
\hline
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\
\hline
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[2-7]

%% TABLE 2
\begin{table*}[t]
\centering
\caption{TABLE 2}
\label{Tab2}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
name & job & title & age & address & status \\
\hline
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\
\hline
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\
\hline
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\
\hline
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\
\hline
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\
\hline
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

%% TABLE 3
\begin{table*}[t]
\centering
\caption{TABLE 3}
\label{Tab3}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
name & job & title & age & address & status \\
\hline
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\
\hline
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\
\hline
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\
\hline
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\
\hline
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\
\hline
Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols & Ida Nichols \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\section{sec2}\label{sec2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but tables are big,  and in such a case, they will cross with the second column. So this method is okay only for small tables. any help!

Comment: @AbdullaAburomman, sorry, how I can know, that your table is big? You show us a small table ...  See edited answer (will appear ASAP)

Comment: :-) my bad, anyway I used \usepackage{stfloats}  but the table still jump to the next section.

Comment: @AbdullaAburomman, than on the page, from where is inserted, is not sufficient space for it. This can not be concluded from information which you privide, Please edit your question, that be more clear, what is your problem.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it is clear now. Thanks

Comment: @AbdullaAburomman, now is far better.  See the second addendum to my answer. However, as I see, your real table with data as indicated in column headers, can spill out of page. Well, this is now off-topic :-).

Comment: Thank you million times, you helped me. now issues are fixed. Best Regards.